# How would I count the number of days based on months with zero data?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm writing a script in which I read in a csv with several columns and rows. I need the script to total the values in each column for a single row and return which columns have a value of zero for the row. Here's an example of what the data looks like, there are several other columns but these are the columns of interest for my question:

```
    JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
     0   0   5   5   0   5   5   5   5   0   0   0
```

this is what I have so far:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import os

    os.chdir('C:\\users\\vroland\\desktop\\RR_WMD\\WUdata')

    fout=open("WUinput.csv","a")
    #read water use file
    df=pd.read_csv("WUtest.csv")
    #Header & months with zero values
    cols=df.columns
    #Boolean array of columns with zero values
    bt=df.apply(lambda x: x==0)
    #List months with zero values
    zar=bt.apply(lambda x:list(cols[x.values]),axis=1)
```

I've tried a combination of ways including `if` statements, but i keep getting an error stating my conditional statement is ambiguous so I'm trying another route. So this is what i have now to go along with the block of code above:

```
   a=30
   b=31
   c=28
   num_days=pd.DataFrame({'JAN':[b],'FEB':[c],'MAR':[b],'APR':[a],'MAY':[b],
                          'JUN':[a],'JUL':[b],'AUG':[b],'SEP':[a],'OCT':[b],
                          'NOV':[a],'DEC':[b]})
```

The idea is to use the values returned in `zar` to look up the appropriate day value in my data frame `num_days`. Return this value and calculate the total number of days with a value of zero.

Comment: "I need the script to total the values in each column for a single row"  doesn't that mean you just want the value in each column?

Comment: Yes I want the value in each column, I was just trying to be as specific as possible, I just didn't want it to be interpreted as I wanted to sum the entire column because each row is a unique event. So, I want the value in each column, sum the nonzero values and return. Next, return the columns with zeros so I can assign the correct number of days according by month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I would get rid of the "fout" line.  You don't seem to write to that file, and it doesn't need to be open to use the "read_csv" feature of pandas.  then you can go through each row and find what's zero, and what isn't

```
returnArray = []
i=0
while i < len(df.values):
    j=14 #since user only cares about column 14-26
    while j < len(df.values[i]):
        if df.values[i][j] == 0:
            returnArray.append([i,j])
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
```

Comment: I could have commented that line, and should have, I'm going to write all of this to another file, just need to get it working correctly first. So is `m_entry` the `df.value` at `i,j`. I need to define it to use it, doesn't want to work as is can you just `int m_entry` in python

Comment: sorry, I revised my code before posting, and didn't thoroughly proofread.  it should make more sense now

Comment: Yeah, gotcha. I'm new to pandas and python for that matter, but using this method it return zero values for all 26 columns of my df, I'm only interested in the last 12 columns. So could I adjust that `len` to only look at columns 14-26?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the `pd.DataFrame` `df`

```
cols = ['JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR',
        'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG',
        'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC']

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 12)), columns=cols)
df
```

[image]

---

I'll use each rows evaluation of `row == 0` to be a boolean mask on the columns themselves.  Use `list` to fit nicely back into a `pd.Series`

```
df.eq(0).apply(lambda x: list(df.columns[x]), 1)

0                   [FEB, MAR, APR, NOV]
1                        [FEB, OCT, NOV]
2              [JAN, APR, AUG, NOV, DEC]
3                        [MAR, APR, SEP]
4                   [MAY, JUN, NOV, DEC]
5                        [APR, AUG, NOV]
6         [MAR, APR, JUN, OCT, NOV, DEC]
7    [JAN, FEB, APR, JUL, OCT, NOV, DEC]
8              [MAY, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT]
9         [FEB, MAR, APR, JUN, AUG, SEP]
dtype: object
```

---

To get the number of days

```
days_in_month = pd.Series(dict(
        JAN=31, FEB=28, MAR=31,
        APR=30, MAY=31, JUN=30,
        JUL=31, AUG=31, SEP=30,
        OCT=31, NOV=30, DEC=31
    ))

df.eq(0).dot(days_in_month)

0    119
1     89
2    153
3     91
4    122
5     91
6    183
7    212
8    154
9    180
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much the output I receive in `zar`. I'm really interested in these lambda functions, what would be a good way to compute total number of days if I'm getting this type of output here.

Comment: Thanks, here's my next question, how do I manipulate `df.eq(0).dot(days_in_month)` to account for the fact that my matrix dimensions are different. In my dataframe I have 26 columns, but I'm only interested in 15-26 in this particular question.